# Azure Website - NodeJS - Crash

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, iisnode, multer

We have an Azure Website under the S1 hosting plan running a Node app and connecting to DocumentDB.  Every time we attempt to upload media into DocumentDB, the node.exe process crashes and restarts.  It doesn't seem to matter the size of the attachment.  When running locally on a Mac I am not running in the iisnode container, just straight node, so it is not something that I have been able to reproduce in my controlled environment.  This essentially causes the app to look frozen or always redirect to the login page.  Here is the code (I am using the 1.0.3 vs of the docdb nodejs sdk):

app.js

```
app.post('/portal/add/media',isAuthenticated, 
  [ multer({ dest: './uploads/'}), portalCrud.addMedia.bind(portalCrud)]);
```

portalCrud.js

```
addMedia: function (req, res) {
    var self = this;
    var file = req.files.attachment;
    var errorCallback = function(error) {
        console.log("Document updated with media ERROR..." + error);
        res.status(error.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: error.message,
            error: error
        });
    };

    var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
    readableStream.on("close", function() {
        fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
    });

    var options = {
        slug: file.originalname,
        contentType: file.mimetype
    };

    // the attachment has been added, now get the parent object to update
    self.dao.getDocument(req.body.docId, false, function (gdErr, parentDocument) {
        handleError(gdErr, errorCallback);
        if(gdErr) return;

        self.dao.addAttachment(parentDocument._self, readableStream, options, function (err, attachment) {
            handleError(err, errorCallback);
            if(err) return;
            res.status(200).send(req.header('Referer'));
        });
    });
}
```

dao.js

```
addAttachment: function (docLink, readableStream, options, callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.client.createAttachmentAndUploadMedia(docLink, readableStream, options, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, resp);
        }
    });
}
```

I am still fairly new to Azure.  I have turned on as much logging as I understand I can, but haven't found anything that indicates an issue.  No events seem to be emitted and I can't seem to enable or find the iisnode logs.  Nothing seems to get logged at d:\home\LogFiles\Application\logging-errors.txt but I can see that whenever I do an upload, the node process gets a new PID like it crashed and restarted. Any hints anybody can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I will provide any information I can to help.

Comment: Have you followed these instructions to debug Node.js apps in Azure Web Apps? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug/

Comment: just tried, can't replicate locally on my Windows dev machine. I would suggest following the steps given by Zain to debug this further. Let us know what you find.

Comment: when you say "just straight node so it is something that I have been able to reproduce in my controlled environment" ... do you mean you HAVE been able to repro locally, or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, should have proofread.  I meant have NOT been able to reproduce.  I will make sure I go through all of the debugging steps and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: If you're using the "new" portal (portal.azure.com), in the settings blade, you click "Diagnostics Logs" and set everything to on. You can then use the "Streaming Logs" to view your logs as they come in. @RyanCrawCour-MSFT, did you try reproing on Azure?

Comment: I followed the debug logging setup instructions as well as ensured that all Diagnostic Logs settings were enabled.  While streaming the logs via the cli tail command, I still don't get any new information.
`POST /portal/add/media 302 859.831 ms - 240
GET /portal/edit/UNOMAVS/TEAM/b2f81bce-eb4a-a906-31d7-256409271bed 302 9.424 ms - 68
GET /login 200 4445.241 ms - 1163`
First the POST of the media, that properly returns a redirect.  Then the GET of the URI that was sent in the redirect.  Then a long wait and since the session is gone a redirect to the /login URI.

Comment: stdout/stderr don't provide any extra detail.  `/site/LogFiles/Application/logging-errors.txt` is empty.  `/LogFiles/DetailedErrors` has a few 404 errors in it, but I suspect that is due to the node service being down or my initial login attempt as I don't currently have 'Always On' enabled.

Comment: I see in the code a reference to './uploads/' ... does this path exist? does the node process have full permissions on this folder?

Comment: One thing I should have noted is that the image does get uploaded properly to DocumentDB and I see the addMedia call finishing properly.  It seems to just be immediately after that in which node crashes.  I am working on putting a bunch more debug logging statements throughout the flow of the code to get more detail.

Comment: I get this error now right after the upload and node crash. I assume it is because the node process died though.  [portal_error.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxntNqfKsAhlWGswQkc5SmltRk0/view?usp=sharing) .  To summarize it; Error 500.1001, The node.exe process has not written any information to stderr or iisnode was unable to capture this information. Frequent reason is that the iisnode module is unable to create a log file to capture stdout and stderr output from node.exe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to come up with a solution to this problem.  After slowly rolling back potential causes it came down to the use of the Node middleware Multer (https://github.com/expressjs/multer) which is essentially a middleware wrapper for BusBoy.  I switched that out for a different module called Multiparty (https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) and just like that, iisnode stopped crashing.

I wasn't getting any logs from iisnode that gave me any information though, so the root cause is still unknown, which is unfortunate by other work is taking priority.  Here is the resulting code in case anybody else happens to run into something similar (the original multer based code can be seen in the original post):

**The express route:**

```
app.post('/portal/add/media',isAuthenticated, portalCrud.addMedia.bind(portalCrud));
```

**The addMedia function:**

```
addMedia: function (req, res) {
    var self = this;
    var callback = function(fields, file, readableStream) {
        var errorCallback = function(error) {
            res.status(error.status || 500);
            res.render('error', {
                message: error.message,
                error: error
            });
        };
        var options = {
            slug: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + "_" + file.originalFilename,  // prepend date in seconds for uniqueness
            contentType: file.headers["content-type"]
        };

        self.dao.getDocument(fields.docId, false, function (gdErr, parentDocument) {
            handleError(gdErr, errorCallback);
            if(gdErr) return;

            self.dao.addAttachment(parentDocument._self, readableStream, options, function (err, attachment) {
                handleError(err, errorCallback);
                if(err) return;

                parentDocument[fields.fieldName] = attachment;

                // update the parent document
                self.dao.updateDocument(parentDocument, function(updErr, updResp) {
                    handleError(updErr, errorCallback);
                    if(updErr) return;

                    fs.unlink(file.path);
                    res.redirect(req.header('Referer') || '/');
                });
            });
        });
    };

    self.fileUploadHelper.uploadFile(req, res, callback);
}
```

**Finally the FileUploadHelper:**

```
FileUploadHelper.prototype = {
    uploadFile: function(req, res, cb, noStream) {
        var fields = {};
        var form = new multiparty.Form();
        form.on('field', function(name, value) {
            fields[name] = value;
        });
        form.on('file', function(name, file) {
            console.log("Upload File >>>");
            console.log("path: " + file.path);
            console.log("filename: " + file.originalFilename);
            console.log("size: " + (file.size / 1024));
            console.log("headers: " + JSON.stringify(file.headers));

            if(noStream) {
                cb(fields, file);
            } else {
                var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
                cb(fields, file, readableStream);
            }
        });

        form.parse(req);
    }
};
```